# How to use alike

Tags: usage

Is the usage of **alike** correct in the following sentence

> Young school students now-a-days are subjected to pressure from peers and parents **alike** to fetch high marks in public examinations.

I think it is correct, but according to my book **equally** should be used in place of **alike**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that that use of "alike" is correct. It could be replaced by "as well". The whole phrase is equivalent to "peers and also parents".  I don't think "equally" fits, because there's no implication that the pressure from the two groups is exactly the same.